# In Qt how to connect a singleton instance to a slot?

Tags: c++, qt, singleton, signals-slots

I'm programming in Qt Creator and encountered a problem. I made a singleton class, and I'm trying to connect it to a slot in the widget, but it doesn't take the pointer that returns
from `Singleton::getInstance()` as the same instance that emits the signal.

My code is as follows:

```
class Widget : public QWidget
{        
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
         explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
         ~Widget();

    private slots:
         void setString(int var);
    }
```

Implementation:

```
connect(Singleton::getInstance(),SIGNAL(changeString(int)),this,SLOT(setString(int)));
```

Signal in the singleton class:

```
signals:
    void changeString(int var);
```

the call to the signal in the singleton class:

```
emit(Singleton::getInstance()->changeString(5));
```

Nothing happens when signal emits. The debugger doesn't enter the slot.

Comment: It would be very beneficial to check out the error message thats coming to stderr when you run the application ? It propably has atleast something about why signal emission or connect fails.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably it's the differing method signature of the slot - `setString(IMSS_Status);` vs. `setString(int);`

Also, in case of a custom type, you should call

> qRegisterMetaType<IMSS_Status>("IMSS_Status");

to register it correctly with the meta type system. Otherwise, queued slot executions won't work, for instance.

Comment: no. i just changed it for the question' and forgot to change all the parts.

Comment: Could it be an error in the singleton implemetation? Maybe getInstance() is returning different instances instead of one. So you're connecting to one instance, but are emitting on another one. Happened to me one time - looked all in the wrong places, as it was just a missing static in my singleton code.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem  may be caused by signature of the  methods.  Before  you make connect  signal with slot  u should define your signal to system by using `qRegisterMetaType<Your Class >("Class Definition name");`

And  is the signal of changeString signature ? "void changeString(int)"

i had encountered your problem and i solved my problem by making qRegisterMetaType and controlling signatures.

Comment: problem solved. it was because something else- nested classes not converted to father class

Answer (score 0):

Does the Singleton class have the `Q_OBJECT` macro also? I don't know if it needs it also or not.

Comment: it needs it. this is the basic condition for signals and slots

Answer (score 0):

I would lean towards `emit(Singleton::getInstance()->changeString(5));` not being correct.

emit should be called from inside a `Singleton` function as follows:

`emit(changeString(5));`

I'm surprised the code you posted compiles and runs without warning, I would have expected a runtime error about the signal not existing.